# Парсинг строки

Tags: java

Есть строка `ps` и массив строк `str`. Я делаю преобразование строки в массив след образом.

```
String ps="Привет Медвед";
String[] str=new String[22];
str=ps.split("");
```

Потом каждый элемент массива передаю в набор данных и вывожу в таблицу. У меня возникает след ошибка. Если вывожу столько элементов массива сколько символов в строке.то норм.А если пытаюсь вывести все символы массива в таблицу,даже если они пустые то ничего выводит.Подскажите пожалуйста,как можно исправить это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String ps="Привет Медвед";
String[] str=new String[22]; // <= эта строка не имеет смысла
str=ps.split("");           // потому что эта создаст новый массив, а старый удалит GC
```

str будет хранить такой массив `["","П","р","и","в","е","т"," ","М","е","д","в","е","д"]` - обратите внимания на первый символ - там пустота. Но если нужно разбить посимвольно, то может проще воспользоваться методом charAt ?

```
for (int i  = 0; i < ps.length;i++) 
   System.out.println(ps.charAt(i));
```

> даже если они пустые то ничего выводит

логично.

Comment: Что такое charAt?можно какнибудь без него

Comment: а зачем без него? charAt - это получить символ строки в заданной позиции. То есть, `ps.charAt(0)` - это первый символ строки `ps`. В других языках программирования обычно пишется проще - `ps[0]`. Но это java:)

Comment: так, как оно хотелось бы

    String s[] = new String[10];
    String t = "hello";
    s[0] = t.charAt(0); 

оно не работает, но есть распространенный подход

    String s[] = new String[10];
    String t = "hello";
    s[0] = ""+t.charAt(0);  // << здесь

Comment: я не знаю, как там происходит заполнение ячеек.

Comment: заполнение идет вот так:
addRow();
 setField("ps1",str[1]);
 setField("ps2",str[2]);
 setField("ps3",str[3]);
 setField("ps4",str[4]);
 setField("ps5",str[5]);

Comment: А почему то вот тем парсингом который написан в вопросе,я загоняю элементы в массив и вывожу способом описанном выше комментарием,получается что нумерация в массивах идет с первого элемента. Да кстати еще хотел заметить,что я работаю с шестой java!

Comment: логично, что тем способом начинается с 1. потому что там есть нулевой элемент, который пустой, а все остальные сдвинуты на одну позицию. Визуально получается, что да, начинается с 1. Хотя по факту размер массива на 1 больше.